# Git push -u origin master: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, gitlab

I created a new git repo using `git init`, and added a git remote:

```
origin  git@gitlab.com:<myname>/<myproject>.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.com:<myname>/<myproject>.git (push)
```

When I try push to my repo using `git push -u origin master`, I get the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, `git push https://gitlab.com/<myname>/<myproject>.git` works. I'm guessing this has to do with SSH keys? I do have a key I generated a year ago for a different project, but I'm not sure what I have to do with it now? Or should I create a new key?

Comment: How do you authenticate yourself to gitlab.com when you use the "git push https: //gitlab.." method?

Comment: It prompts me for my gitlab username and password. 
On the other hand, `git push -u origin master` doesn't ask for that.

Answer (score 1):

It is the ssh key which is the issue.
You will have to update the remote key storage with your public key, that should fix it.